# Hide home screen shortcuts

Tags: android

Is there a way to just **HIDE** the shortcuts on the home screen.I don't want to remove them completely, just hide them for some time.

Comment: You mean programmatically ?

Comment: And what do you mean hide? Putting into a folder is sufficient?

Comment: Shortcuts placed there by the user or another application?  No, and there shouldn't be.  That's basically a ransomeware technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app not to be shown in launcher, 
remove intent filter that has `LAUNCHER` category from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```